# Interbase 6 and stored procedure array parameters

Tags: stored-procedures, parameters, interbase

Does Interbase 6 database support passing array parameter to stored procedure? If yes what is the syntax of declaring such variable and using it in the body of procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like even the current version of IB does not support array parameters.

The documentation includes an example of processing array data within the stored procedure to flatten it out, then passing several flat records out of the stored procedure. Of course you could do all this in IB 6 as well.

This example is in the Data Definition manual for XE. See Using stored procedures.

The [Interbase documentation on this topic](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/interbase/IB2009/IB2009_DataDef.pdf) may be useful.

Comment: It would be nice if you mentioned name of stored procedure you are referring to and page number to resolve ambiguities.